# 7 segments display LED, need some explaination

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

First of all this is my first project, I have 0 experience of verilog. My professor never teach us verilog but he gave out the project regardless. So I really need some help.
I use vivado 2014.4 and basys 3 board. My goal is when I hit a push_botton the 4-7 segments displays light up.
This is what I wrote base on 3 hours of research
Constraint file

```
#Push button
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {pb}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {pb}]

#7 segment display

set_property PACKAGE_PIN W7 [get_ports {seg[0]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[0]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN W6 [get_ports {seg[1]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[1]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN U8 [get_ports {seg[2]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[2]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN V8 [get_ports {seg[3]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[3]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN U5 [get_ports {seg[4]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[4]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN V5 [get_ports {seg[5]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[5]}]

set_property PACKAGE_PIN U7 [get_ports {seg[6]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[6]}]


set_property PACKAGE_PIN V7 [get_ports {seg[7]}]                            
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {seg[7]}]

    set_property PACKAGE_PIN U2 [get_ports {an[0]}]                    
        set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[0]}]

    set_property PACKAGE_PIN U4 [get_ports {an[1]}]                    
        set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[1]}]

    set_property PACKAGE_PIN V4 [get_ports {an[2]}]                    
        set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[2]}]

    set_property PACKAGE_PIN W4 [get_ports {an[3]}]                    
        set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[3]}]
```

And then I stuck in design source

```
`timescale 1ns/ 1ps
module project (
input pb,
output [7:0] seg,
output [2:0] an
);
-I have no idea how to translate this pseudocode to verilog
if (pb == 1) begin
seg[7:0] = 8'b00001111;
an[0] = seg;
end
```

That is the whole idea but I don't know how to write it. Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get you started see code below. Hold `pb` to 1 for the output to change, release and outputs go back to zero.

You probably should add a clock in there so you can debounce or at least put `pb` through some meta-stability flip-flops.

`an` is 3 bits wide, but you had 1 bit of it pointed at the 8 bit seg in your pseudo code. I have commented that line out as not sure what it is meant to be.

```
module project (
  input pb,
  output [7:0] seg,
  output [2:0] an
);
  always @* begin 
    if (pb == 1) begin
      seg[7:0] = 8'b00001111;
      //an[0] = seg;
    end
    else begin
      seg[7:0] = 8'b0;
      //an       = 'b0;
    end
  end

endmodule
```

You might want read up on Verilog at [Verilog in one day](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/verilog_one_day.html).

Comment: Somehow it's always turn on.

Comment: And 1 more thing, how can I discrete which seven segment display will light up if I didn't modify an (anode) value?